# docker: invalid reference format, variable name contains `=`

Tags: docker, shell, zsh

I am trying to pass env variables to the  container `app-name_app-name` and it's failing as follows. I am trying to pass in env variable thru command line, seems like problem is related to the fact I have an equals `=` sign in my env variable.

```
docker run --env FERNET_KEY=Jo9HlTULeWylXz39Q25v9cqsHx4_7ZDAHlsQPuJiiHY=  APP_DB_PASSWORD=gAAAAABhRil3bGI9o_nCmMEf6oJ3cBuMD6y9to6GX05apQp2GO3GPkxrmeOLBfzeKNPPsp_P8vX2tma3EUEM7m5DuI94K84riA== localhost:5000/app-name_app-name

docker: invalid reference format: repository name must be lowercase.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

I am using `zsh` as a shell, I have also tried `sh` and `bash` and results are the same

Comment: Is there a second `-e` before `APP_DB_PASSWORD`?  Missing that would cause this error.

Comment: @DavidMaze : Should this be `-e` really, or `-env` again?

Comment: Either, [they're the same](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#set-environment-variables--e---env---env-file).

Comment: @DavidMaze yes missing —env was the case